# Symfony2 Api-Platform bin/schema issue

Tags: symfony, console, api-platform.com

I've just started [Api-Platform](https://api-platform.com/doc/1.0/getting-started/api) framework and while executing:

```
php bin/schema generate-types src/ app/config/schema.yml
```

I get this:

```
C:\wamp\www\sf2-api>php bin/schema generate-types src/ app/config/schema.yml

dir=$(d=${0%[/\\]*}; cd "$d"; cd "../vendor/api-platform/schema-generator/bin" &
& pwd)

# See if we are running in Cygwin by checking for cygpath program
if command -v 'cygpath' >/dev/null 2>&1; then
        # Cygwin paths start with /cygdrive/ which will break windows PHP,
        # so we need to translate the dir path to windows format. However
        # we could be using cygwin PHP which does not require this, so we
        # test if the path to PHP starts with /cygdrive/ rather than /usr/bin
        if [[ $(which php) == /cygdrive/* ]]; then
                dir=$(cygpath -m $dir);
        fi
fi

dir=$(echo $dir | sed 's/ /\ /g')
"${dir}/schema" "$@"
```

I am using Symfony 2.7.8 on window7.
I have the same issue on ubunbu 14.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I replace the bin directory with the one in [blog-api](https://github.com/dunglas/blog-api).

**Updated:**

[image]

- The bin-api-platform is the one generated by api-platform.
- The bin-blog-api is the one I copy from blog-api. This works fine.

Comment: Can you post a diff between the two files (I've not a Windows box to test)?

Answer (score 0):

Use :

```
php vendor/api-platform/schema-generator/bin/schema generate-types src/app/config/schema.yml
```

instead of :

```
php bin/schema generate-types src/ app/config/schema.yml
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is:

`php vendor/api-platform/schema-generator/bin/schema generate-types src/ app/config/schema.yml`

Comment: This maybe correct but you should explain your answer more

Comment: Call the function that would be `php vendor/api-platform/schema-generator/bin/schema`  First parameter is `generate-types` because that's what you want.  Second parameter is the destination folder's path `src/` ( but it will add 'AppBundle/Entity' to your real path, so it will be `src/AppBundle/Entity` )  Third parameter will be the schema.yml file path.